# Water drops on camera

Tags: unity, shaders

How can I create water drops on camera something like we see in Ripitude GP, 
[image]

I tried using Unity's default GlassStainedBumpDistort shader though its performance heavy on mobile plus it do not let animate water drops.

Comment: Distortion mapping is always very performance-intense. Would it be an option to just use run-off-the-mill transparent 2d sprites on a GUI canvas for the water drops? Would not look as well as proper distortion, but would definitely be a lot easier on the hardware.

Comment: Maybe finding a shader that doesn't do a proper distortion but just shifts everything by 1 pixel that's inside the water drop mask would be faster and (combined with actual water drop sprites) would look good enough.